# Core data migration - do I need a migration model if I do not need to keep data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, database-migration

Very basic question here - I am implementing CoreData into an existing project. Whilst doing so and whilst playing around, the model is constantly changing during this dev period. The data I have been saving is clearly just test data that I have no need to keep.

My question is, do I really need to migrate this or is there a simple way just to wipe the old db and schema and implement my new model?

Comment: No migration needed.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I just delete out the old database and replace with the new one

Comment: Just delete the old database files, new ones will be created automatically